# SNS message attribute not being parsed correctly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I send an SNS message from AWS console with the following message attributes:

```
Type: String
Name: is_data
Value: false
```

The SNS is received by an SQS and it gets parsed in a Lambda function.

The SQS message body has the following fields:

```
   "MessageAttributes": {
        "is_data": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "false"
        }
```

However when I try to parse it, it throws error:

```
void f(SQSMessage sqsMessage) {
String messageBody = sqsMessage.getBody();
JsonNode body = objectMapper.readTree(messageBody);

Map<String, SNSEvent.MessageAttribute> messageAttributeMap =
            objectMapper.convertValue(body.get("MessageAttributes"),
                                      new TypeReference<Map<String, SNSEvent.MessageAttribute>>(){});
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "Type" (class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SNSEvent$MessageAttribute), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "value", "type"])
```

What am I missing?

Why does SNS send "**T**ype" and "**V**alue" whereas the class expects "type" and "value" ?

Comment: That is not legal JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the ObjectMapper to be case insensitive:

```
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```